# ASP .NET Application authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication

I want implement .NET web site with AD authentication, If site is accessed  internally then it should **automatically login** with current user. 
**BUT** if site is access out site organization then it should redirect user to **custom login** for where user can enter **AD login details**.

Can anyone guide how we can achieve this functionally what configuration required.

ASP

.NET

IIS Configuration

Firewall (if required)
Any other configuration required.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can't automatically log a user into your website using AD. The website knows nothing at all about the client's machine and one way or another they must enter this information for your site to know about it. In your website you could write a custom authentication method that uses AD, or you can use an IIS module but both will prompt the user for login information regardless.

Comment: By your question, it looks you have no clue how ASP.NET Authentication works behind the scenes. I'd suggest you to spend some time learning how ASP.NET pipeline works for such project, because what you are asking here is a guide. I believe questions in SO are more likely to be answered when you have specific problems. Once you start something by yourself, if you get any problem when trying to implement your solution, then you should ask here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do that by [enabling Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs) and dealing with 401 Not Authorized results by checking, if user is authenticated(means he is Windows user, but is not authorized to access resource) or he is not authenticated it means he is not Windows user and you can redirect him to login page.

You have to take care of restrictions on Windows users and stuff around, but I believe it is possible to do that, even I am not a big fan of such authentication solution.